# SOLID principles and how to actually implement them

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, solid-principles

Lately I've been tinkering with TDD and coding based on the SOLID principles .  I have a scenario as follows:

- One can have `IRecurringProfile`, which performs a series of payments on an interval, e.g monthly basis
- When a payment tries to go through and it fails, a `IRecurringProfileTransaction` is created linked to the `IRecurringProfilePayment` to show that the payment did not go through.
- The failure count for the payment is incremented.
- The date/time for which to retry payment and send another failure notification (if payment is failed) is also updated.
- If the failure count for a payment reaches a maximum threshold (e.g 3 failed attempts), the `IRecurringProfile` is suspended.
- Also, with each failure, a notification is sent to inform the client that the payment did not go through, and will be retried again.

Below is some sample code I created, which mainly deals with the task of marking a recurring profile payment as failed.  I tried to follow on the SOLID principles, as well as constructor injection.  Would like to know if this is violating any of these principles or any programming best-practices, and subject the code to any form of scrutiny so that it can be improved.  The code also uses NHibernate as the ORM.

```
public class RecurringPaymentMarkAsFailure
{
    private readonly IPaymentFailedNotificationSender paymentFailedNotificationSender;
    private readonly IRecurringProfileFailureNextNotificationDateUpdater failureNotificationDateUpdater;
    private readonly IRecurringProfileSuspender recurringProfileSuspender;

    public RecurringPaymentMarkAsFailure(IPaymentFailedNotificationSender paymentFailedNotificationSender, IRecurringProfileSuspender recurringProfileSuspender,
        IRecurringProfileFailureNextNotificationDateUpdater failureNotificationDateUpdater)
    {
        this.paymentFailedNotificationSender = paymentFailedNotificationSender;
        this.failureNotificationDateUpdater = failureNotificationDateUpdater;

        this.recurringProfileSuspender = recurringProfileSuspender;

    }

    private void checkProfileStatus(IRecurringProfile profile)
    {
        if (profile.Status != Enums.RecurringProfileStatus.Active)
        {
            throw new Exceptions.RecurringProfileException("This cannot be called when the profile is not marked as active");
        }
    }


    private void incrementFailureCount(IRecurringProfilePayment payment)
    {
        payment.FailureCount++;
    }

    public IRecurringProfileTransaction MarkPaymentAsFailed(IRecurringProfilePayment payment, string failureData)
    {
        using (var t = BeginTransaction())
        {
            checkProfileStatus(payment.RecurringProfile);


            IRecurringProfileTransaction transaction = payment.Transactions.CreateNewItem();
            transaction.OtherData = failureData;
            transaction.Status = Enums.RecurringProfileTransactionStatus.Failure;
            paymentFailedNotificationSender.CreateAndQueueNotification(transaction);
            failureNotificationDateUpdater.UpdateNextFailureNotificationDate(payment);
            incrementFailureCount(payment);

            if (payment.FailureCount >= payment.RecurringProfile.MaximumFailedAttempts)
            {
                recurringProfileSuspender.SuspendRecurringProfile(payment.RecurringProfile);
            }
            transaction.Save();
            t.Commit();
            return transaction;
        }

    }

}
```

--

As a side note, this question complements my most recent post about a similar topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see it, you are violating the Single Responsibility Principle, since your `RecurringPaymentMarkAsFailure` has two responsibilities. Besides the responsibility of makring the payment as a failure, it also adds the responsibility of managing the transaction (the `using (BeginTransaction)`; that is a cross-cutting concern.

You will probably have many classes like these in the system that handle business logic, and probably all (or many) have this exact same transaction code. Instead, consider adhering to the Open/Closed Principle by allowing to add this behavior as decorator. This is well possible, because the transaction is the first AND last operation in this code. A naive implementation of this decorator could look like this:

```
public class TransactionRecurringPaymentMarkAsFailureDecorator
    : RecurringPaymentMarkAsFailure
{
    private RecurringPaymentMarkAsFailure decoratedInstance;

    public RecurringPaymentMarkAsFailure(
        RecurringPaymentMarkAsFailure decoratedInstance)
    {
        this.decoratedInstance = decoratedInstance;
    }

    public override IRecurringProfileTransaction MarkPaymentAsFailed(
        IRecurringProfilePayment payment, string failureData)
    {
        using (var t = BeginTransaction())
        {
            var transaction = this.decoratedInstance
                .MarkPaymentAsFailed(payment, failureData);

            t.Commit();

            return transaction;
        }
    }
}
```

This decorator allows you to wrap the class as follows:

```
var marker =
    new TransactionRecurringPaymentMarkAsFailureDecorator(
        new RecurringPaymentMarkAsFailure(
            /* dependencies */    
        ));
```

As I said this implementation is a bit naive, since you will probably have many classes that need to be wrapped, and this means that each class would get its own decorator. Although this is completely SOLID, it isn't DRY.

Instead, let all classes that execute use cases implement a single generic interface, something like `ICommandHandler<TCommand>`. This allows you to create a single generic `TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand>` class to wrap all those instances. Take a look at this article to learn more about this model: [Meanwhile… on the command side of my architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).

Comment: What would be the two responsibilities? The linked article is a very good read - I'm currently looking into trying to implement a generic decorator pattern to the posted code.

Comment: The first responsibility is the actual business logic. The other responsibility is running everything in a database transaction (which is a cross-cutting concern). Changing your transaction strategy is not something you would change at the same time as you change the business logic.

Comment: I've been trying the decorator & command approach and it makes sense.  However my main issue is if there is an optimistic concurrency exception, in that case normally what I would do is refresh the database item, and perform the same code.  I tried creating a `DbOptimisticConcurrencyRetryDecorator`, and it works.  However, when it calls the `MarkAsFailureCommand.Handle()`, this has no way of knowing that it needs to refresh the database item due to to optimistic concurrency error.  Any ideas about how one can deal with that?

Comment: Ideally, this 'refresh' thing is something which the `DbOptimisticConcurrencyRetryDecorator` should do.  However, if this is a general class, it does not have any way to easily know of any database items (my opinion).

Comment: @Steven, Your blog is fantastic. Very much appreciated!

Comment: @KarlCassar: Your business operations should normally run in a clean context. This means their own DbContext, Connection, and Transaction. This means that when the operation fails and you reexecute that operation (using your retry decorator) this should happen in a new context, connection and transaction. If I understand your problem correctly, since you have a clean context, you don't have to retry at all. Just just start all over again. I think that your `DbOptimisticConcurrenccyRetryDecorator` is much like the `DeadlockRetryCommandHandlerDecorator<T>` as described in that blog post.

Comment: @Steven Yes, it should be retried.  However, take this case for example, having the MarkAsFailed command - It increments the failure count of a `RecurringPayment` starting from 0.  Imagine for some reason a different user (thread) also calls MarkAsFailed(), while this is working on it and successfully completes it. This 2nd call would have set the FailureCount to 1. Now if thread #1 is retried due to concurrency exception, it must be on the updated data (FailureCount = 1), so that it now becomes 2. However, the MarkAsFailed command has no way of knowing that now it needs to refresh the object.

Comment: The problem is in your design. You supply an existing entity from the outside into the command. This is means that the command is not autonomous anymore. The only thing you should supply is an ID of that entity, and at that point you should fetch that entity from the database. In that case, when you retry the operation, the entity is refetched, simply because that command runs in a new DbContext.

Comment: @Steven That would work, however I have two issues with that - First of all if the database object is already available prior to the call to this method, isn't it 'wasteful' to have to re-fetch the object? ORM's like NHibernate retrieve such an item from 1st-level cache if already loaded, but still I find it wasteful.  Second, if the parameter was to be changed to a `long` (ID), it would allow consumers of the method to pass any primary key, not just an `IRecurringProfile` and make it less obvious for consumers what they need to pass.

Comment: @KarlCassar: This seems like premature optimization to me. Over the past years I experienced that the performance of commands are hardly ever a problem. And in your case, what do you rather want, a fast system or a correct system? And I bet it will be fast enough. Besides, from the side of the business layer, it's a mere coincident that this data was already loaded. About loosing compile time support when using id's, there are simply ways around this. For instance, use a constructor that accepts an entity, but stores it's id.